# conditional vs unconditional forecast variance in AR(1)

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting, autoregressive

I have trouble showing that conditional forecast error of AR(1) has smaller variance than the unconditional one.

I can show that cond. forecast error is: 
$$ 
Y_{T+1}=aY_{T}+\epsilon_{T+1} $$
$$
\hat{Y}_{T+1}=E[aY_T+\epsilon_{T+1}|Y_T,Y_{T-1},...]=aY_T $$
$$
E[Y_{T+1}-\hat{Y}_{T+1}]=E[\epsilon_{T+1}]=0 $$
$$
Var[Y_{T+1}-\hat{Y}_{T+1}]=E[(Y_{T+1}-\hat{Y}_{T+1})^2]=E[\epsilon^2_{T+1}]=\sigma^2
$$

now trying to get unconditional forecast error (w. help from plissken's answer)
$$
\hat{Y}_{T+1}=E[aY_T+\epsilon_{T+1}]=aE[Y_T]+E[\epsilon_{T+1}]=aE[Y_T]=0 $$
$$E[Y_{T+1}]=E[aY_T+\epsilon_{T+1}]=aE[Y_T]+E[\epsilon_{T+1}]=aE[Y_T]=0$$
$$Var[Y_{T+1}]=E[Y^2_{T+1}]=aE[Y^2_T]+2aE[Y_T\epsilon_{T+1}]+E[\epsilon^2_{T+1}]=\sigma^2/(1-\alpha^2)$$
$$E[Y_{T+1}-\hat{Y}_{T+1}]=aE[Y_{T+1}]+E[\epsilon_{T+1}]-aE[Y_T]=0$$
$$Var[Y_{T+1}-\hat{Y}_{T+1}]=E[(Y_{T+1}-\hat{Y}_{T+1})^2]=E[(Y_{T+1}-E[\hat{Y}_{T+1}])^2]=E[Y^2_{T+1}]=\sigma^2/(1-\alpha^2)$$

not sure if this correct. would be nice if anyone could confirm/help.

greets

Comment: if this is HW please consider adding the [`self-study`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag

Comment: As it stands your last expression is missing something and it is actually less than $\sigma^{2}$. See my edit below.

Comment: good morning sir, thanks for your input! actually my last expression is bigger than sigma², if we assume stable AR(1) - |a|<1. U get a different result, because there is a mistake in X. it should be $$X=\alpha^2V[Y_{T}]$$. The uncond. forecast error therefore should be $$ V[Y_{T+1}-\hat{Y}_{T+1}]=V[Y_{T+1}-E[aY_T+\epsilon_{T+1}]]=V[Y_{T+1}]=\alpha^2V[Y_T]+\sigma^2=\alpha^2\sigma^2/(1-\alpha^2)+\sigma^2=\sigma^2/(1-\alpha^2) $$

Comment: I guess the key point is, that I "forgot" the sequence is still stationary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll need to find the unconditional mean and variance of the AR(1) process $Y_{t}=aY_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t},\;\varepsilon_{t}\sim\left(0,\,\sigma^{2}\right)$:

$$E\left[Y_{t}\right]=E\left[aY_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t}\right]=aE\left[Y_{t-1}\right]+E\left[\varepsilon_{t}\right]=0$$

$$V\left[Y_{t}\right] =V\left[aY_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t}\right]
 =a^{2}V\left[Y_{t-1}\right]+V\left[\varepsilon_{t}\right]
 =\frac{\sigma^{2}}{1-a^{2}}$$

Here I have assumed that the process is stationary, i.e. $\left|a\right|<1
 $ so I can write $E\left[Y_{t}\right]=E\left[Y_{t-1}\right]$.

Then you'll have to find the unconditional variance of the forecast error:

$V\left[Y_{t+1}-\hat{Y}_{t+1}\right]=E\left[\left(aY_{t+1}+\varepsilon_{t+1}-E\left[Y_{t}\right]\right)\right]^{2}=X +\sigma^{2}$.

You'll need to find an expression for $X
 $. Then you'll see that $X +\sigma^{2}>\sigma^{2}$
  as $X>0$.

**EDIT**

Note that $X+\sigma^{2}=V\left[aY_{t+1}+\varepsilon_{t+1}\right]$ since $E\left[Y_{t}\right]=0$. Then it is quick to find $X$ as $X=V\left[aY_{t+1}\right]=a^{2}V\left[Y_{t+1}\right]$. This is not the same as the last expression you have found above.

Comment: thanks for your fast response! of course I assumed a stable process; but E[Y] should be 0 ?!

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by $E\left[Y_{t}\right]=0$. We know that $E\left[Y_{t}\right]=\frac{1}{1-a}$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get why $$E[Y_t]=1/1(1-\alpha) $$. I think it should be 0, since $$ \epsilon_t$$ is zero mean.

Comment: Haha. Don't know what I was thinking there. You are of course correct! It should just be easier to show the above result holds.